# How to listen to changes that are made by other users only?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collaboration platform where multiple users can edit a document. When a user edits a document, they send the new state to the firebase to which other users listen. Those other users then update their state of the document.

Problem is, the listener also gets executed for the local user, even though they are the one who sent the data. This is undesired since the user has already updated their own state.

How to listen to changes that are made by other users only?

For comparison, `socket.io` has a `broadcast()` function that does exactly this. Why doesn't firebase have this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible.  A listener is always going to pick up on all changes to data in a document.  It is effectively just synchronizing the current state of the document in all situations.  It's also possible that a listener will miss an update and just receive the most recent copy of a document (for example, while offline or under load).

If you must be able to discern which user made a change, you should instead store a history of changes (deltas) of the document, each in a new document with the UID of the user making the change, and have clients only act on the changes that come from users of interest.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I'm currently doing but it always felt like a hack.

Comment: The problem is that you're thinking of Firestore as a message broadcasting system, but it's not that at all.  It's a document query and synchronization system.  It doesn't deal with what you think of as messages and broadcasts.